# JavaScript - Minecraft Authentication Error

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, minecraft

Im trying to authenticate my self using the mojang Yggdrasil api, however its giving me this error, the api is https://wiki.vg/Authentication

```
var jsonTest = '{"agent": { "name": "Minecraft", "version": 1 }, 
"username": "test", "password": "password"}';

var url = "https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
req.send(jsonTest);
```

Its giving me this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Check the documentation, as the error suggests you're probably missing a required authentication key

Comment: Checks the docs, not sure what Im missing..

Comment: The server replies with an explanation for the error. Post it here. Looks like it might be a wrong password.

Comment: Tried with the right password and it still shows that error.